# Find the pair of values $a[i]$, $a[j]$ such that $a[i]\,\&\,a[j]$ is maximum

Tags: algorithms, binary

Given a list of positive integers, find the largest possible value of $a[i]$ $\&$ $a[j]$, where $i$, $j$ are indices of the list. $ i\ne j $, $a[i]\,\&\,a[j]$ is bitwise AND of $a[i]$ and $a[j]$.

I need to find a linearithmic or linear time algorithm to solve the problem.

I think, I need to choose one number such that it's highest one bit is maximum, in the list of numbers, and then, the other number should have zeroes where the first one has ones, and vice-versa.

However, I am unable to frame a proper algorithm from the above idea.

Comment: $a[i] \& a[j]$ is bitwise AND of $a[i]$ and $a[j]$? Where did you come across this problem? What is wrong with the trivial $\Theta(n^2)$ brute force algorithm? Is this a puzzle you are posing here?

Comment: I need to solve it in linear or linearithmic time.
I can only guess that converting all numbers to their binary form and then choosing one of the numbers with the highest one bit might be useful. But then, I am unable to figure out how I could go ahead after that.

Comment: You haven't clarified the bitwise AND part (this is a mathematics site :-)). Also, as written, the question gives the impression that you haven't put any effort into it, which clearly isn't true. Why not edit the question and put in some motivation and your ideas and requirement of a linearithmic algorithm, and turn this into good question (according to the standards of this site)?

Comment: @Aryabhata [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/879308/) is a better written version of the same problem, posted at about the same time.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday: Thanks, I have cast my dupe vote there.

Answer (score 3):

Log time is clearly not possible in an unsorted array, but here is an O(n k) time algo where k is number of bits the numbers can have:

Assume integers are given in binary representation.

Set 'prefix' to empty.

for i from 1 to k:
{
  Count = number of integers in the list which start with prefix followed by 1.

If count is at least 2 then append 1 to prefix else append 0 to it
}

At the end, interpret prefix as a k bit integer m. Then the maximum and is m. We can do some extra bookkeeping to find the elements which got to m (store any two elements from last set which led to updating of count)

Comment: Yes, this works nicely. But just to make it explicit: the description of the algorithm assumes that all the binary representations have length k (after padding on the left with zeroes if necessary).

Comment: Yes that is the assumption, thanks for making it explicit